# Substitute for refined white flour to make fried potato wedges crispy?

Tags: substitutions, flour

I used to make potato wedges using refined flour, using this [recipe](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=fvwp&v=GIktMV0ogLc&NR=1). Basically refined flour and corn flour is used to provide extra crisp to potato wedges. The parboiled wedges are coated in a mixture from the flour and some seasonings, then frozen and deep-fried.

But while net surfing I came across [harmful effects](http://www.care2.com/greenliving/7-negative-effects-of-refined-flour.html) of refined white flour. Is there a substitute for refined flour? Or are there other ways to get crispy wedges?

Comment: Perhaps you can transcribe the recipe (or at least describe the use of flour in it) so we don't have to sit through the video?

Comment: I sat through the video so I gave a somewhat longer summary of how the flour is used

Comment: We're not a health site, so this (my comment) is off-topic, but... you're worried about the health effects of a relatively small amount of flour in something you're *deep frying* ‽

Comment: To be clear about what it means that we're not a health site, there is a second question, not explicitly asked: are the claims about flour being harmful true? That is outside the scope and expertise of Seasoned Advice. So you won't get an answer to that part here. But it may be the case that it isn't true, unfortunately I don't think the network has a good site to ask that on.

Comment: @derobert i am asking for substitution...not about harmful effects, i mentioned it as a reason for not using it further.

Comment: @SunishthaSingh Understood, just want to be clear about it, in case some future visitor sees the question and, not seeing anything talking about the health effects, assumes we've vetted them.

Comment: Sunishtha, when I edited your answer, I fixed a lot of things, and left the meaning completely intact. We really do like to have good writing on StackExchange sites, and community editing is one of the ways we accomplish that. Is there some reason you rolled it back?

Comment: @Jefromi that is due to server slow n my system was hanged....i didn't wished to rollback...m thnkful to your help in fixing my question.

Answer (score 6):

You could substitute any flour you like, the purpose of the coating is to give it some extra crisp when frying. I would suggest maybe rice flour or you could use whole wheat flour but the taste may be different.

IMO, I would skip that step altogether though. A potato wedge is just a french fry cut in a different shape and we don't dredge french fries.

Comment: Any starch really...  many people do dredge or batter french fries.  It is not the most common method, but it is out there.  CF Burger King on the fast food front.

Comment: While you can make wedges without this step, using the aromatic flour will give you a different result than without. It would be about the same difference as between a schnitzel and an escalope - similar, but not the same. If the OP likes the taste, I would suggest to not leave it out.

Comment: Yeah true, i forgot about that atrocious "fry".

Comment: You can add the aromatics to the wedges post-fry as a seasoning though.

Comment: @Brendan Did  not say I *liked* them....

Comment: Good on you for that!

Answer (score 6):

The coating of flour serves two purposes at once. First, it carries flavor - the flour-seasoning mix sticks better to the potatoes than a seasoning-only mixture could. Second, it gives you a crisp texture, absorbing oil, without letting much oil through to the actual potato, to prevent it from getting greasy.

For both, the closer you get to pure starch, the better results you will get. You can use a refined flour or starch made from practically any tuber or grain with good results. Which one you choose is probably a matter of practicality, as not all of them are equally available everywhere.

If you want to come away from the starch, whole-grain flours will also work reasonably well. Choose finely ground ones and be aware that most of them will introduce their own taste. This can be an advantage or disadvantage, depending on whether you like the taste combination. I would refrain from the strongest tasting ones such as maize flour.

I would advise against legume or nut flours. They contain even less starch than whole grain flours, but exactly for this reason they will fail at the two roles I noted above.

If you are asking yourself why you would want to go to alternatives with less starch: most of the concerns this article has about "refined white flour" (which happens to be about 90% wheat starch) are commonly expressed for all kinds of starch (except for numbers 5 and 6 which are wheat-specific). So, if you believe the article, you should avoid everything well-suited as a replacement for the flour, and look for alternatives which deliver an acceptable result while introducing less starch into your diet. While researching this, don't forget that the potatoes will deliver the largest starch amount in this recipe anyway, so if you decide to reduce starch consumption, you should probably remove this from the menu altogether.

Comment: FWIW, we used Taro root powder at the restaurant I used to work at.

Answer (score 0):

I find whole oat flour provides an excellent crispyness to fried veggies. I mill my own from steel cut groats, but you can probably either buy the stuff, or make it in small quantities from groats or oatmeal with a spinning blade type spice grinder.

Comment: ty for the option will try it out n get back to you with experience.